# Powershell psexec JOB

Tags: powershell, jobs, psexec

I tried this from another post at Stackoverflow:

```
$serverlist=$listbox1.SelectedItems

$jobs = foreach ($serverName in $serverlist) {
  Start-Job -Name "PingJob $serverName" -ArgumentList $serverName -ScriptBlock {
      param($serverName)
      if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $serverName -Count 1 -Quiet)
      {
        C:\Localbin\PsExec.exe -s \\$serverName ping cadc02 -n 30 > \\$serverName\pingresult\$serverName.txt
      }
   }
}

$jobs | Wait-Job 
$jobs | Receive-Job
```

It works and the output files are created, but the full data is missing. It just says

```
Pinging cadc02.xyz.net [192.168.100.2]
```

but the rest of the lines like

```
Reply from 192.168.200.3: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Ping statistics for 192.168.200.3:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

is missing.

Comment: Have you tried running the command from PS/commandline outside of the script? Any other errors/error codes pop up? Tried your code here and it works fine, logs all lines.

Comment: If you mean running just the part "C:\Localbin\PsExec.exe -s \\$serverName ping cadc02 -n 30 > \\$serverName\pingresult\$serverName.txt" - then yes it works. For example running only with foreach (serially ) works perfectly

Comment: Yes, I didn't run it with the jobs code. If that is where it breaks it must be something with the stream outputting to file *within* a job. Tried the entire code now. Same results as you...

Answer (score 0):

How about this code:

```
$serverlist=$listbox1.SelectedItems

$jobs = foreach ($serverName in $serverlist) {
  Start-Job -Name "PingJob $serverName" -ArgumentList $serverName -ScriptBlock {
      param($serverName)
      if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $serverName -Count 1 -Quiet)
      {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverName -ScriptBlock { & ping cadc02 -n 30 } > "C:\temp\$serverName.txt"
      }
   }
}

$jobs | Wait-Job 
$jobs | Receive-Job
```

There is one big "if" with this code, and that is it uses Powershell remoting via the Invoke-Command instead of System Internals psexec.

If psexec is a requirement (you can't powershell-remote the computers for some reason) then this won't work for you.

Also: Change the "C:\temp\" in the code for a local folder that works for you.